# How do I get complex types to initialize and work for declaring data in a vue.js module

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to use a class I created in TypeScript called `Budget` to initialize data for a module.

If I do something like

```
currBudget: {} = { id: 20, name: 'Chris' };
```

everything works fine, but if I do

```
currBudget: Budget;
```

where `Budget` is a class that is imported into the component, it doesn't make the data available even though the `Budget` class has the same fields declared in it and set to default values.

Is there some kind of weird syntax in typescript where that won't work? Do I ned to declare `Budget` as an interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax

```
currBudget: Budget;
```

only declares `currBudget` as of type `Budget`. It doesn't initialize it.

To define its type and also initialize it, do:

```
currBudget: Budget = new Budget();
```